# Different output in leetcode and visual studio code for python (4. Median)

Tags: python, testing

Recently I've just taken an interest in learning python, however, this one has really defeated me.
The specific question on Leetcode is "4. Median of Two Sorted Arrays":

Given two sorted arrays nums1 and nums2 of size m and n respectively, return the median of the two sorted arrays.

The overall run time complexity should be O(log (m+n)).

I have tried to crake it by forming half of the final list (length would be "con") of the combined two arrays first by the use of accumulator "coffin" (an empty list to put elements in) and "pos" (counting the length of the generated list, if it is more than half of "con", the loop stops and returns the median), then find the median using list methods. However, to do this I relied on len(), which works in visual studio but apparently gives wrong output in Leetcode's checking system.

```
def fn(nums1,nums2):
    pos = -1
    coffin = []
    con = len(nums1) + len(nums2)
    for i in nums1:
        for x in nums2:
            if x > i:
                coffin.append(i)
                pos += 1
                break
            #if x == i: # Median doesn't account for repeated number? for leetcode
                coffin.append(i)
                coffin.append(x)
                nums2 = nums2[1:]
                pos += 2
                break
            else:
                coffin.append(x)
                nums2 = nums2[1:]
                pos += 1
            if pos >= con / 2:
                if con % 2 == 0:
                    return (coffin[int(con / 2 -1)] + coffin[int(con / 2)]) / 2
                else:
                    return coffin[int(con/2)]
    for e in nums2:
        coffin.append(e)
        pos += 1
        if pos >= con / 2:
                if con % 2 == 0:
                    return (coffin[int(con / 2 -1)] + coffin[int(con / 2)]) / 2
                else:
                    return coffin[int(con/2)]
```

fn([1,2],[3,4) gives 2.5 in visual studio code, but gives 2.0 in Leetcode.

I suspect that the Leetcode stored the "con" value from previous test (input: [1,2], [3]), but since the values are defined inside the function they should be renewed every time new input is given...?

apparently people in the comment section are getting the correct answers in leetcode, I should post the one on leetcode as well then.

```
class Solution(object):
def findMedianSortedArrays(self, nums1, nums2):
    pos = -1
    coffin = []
    con = len(nums1) + len(nums2)
    for i in nums1:
        for x in nums2:
            if x > i:
                coffin.append(i)
                pos += 1
                break
            #if x == i: # Median doesn't account for repeated number? for leetcode
                coffin.append(i)
                coffin.append(x)
                nums2 = nums2[1:]
                pos += 2
                break
            else:
                coffin.append(x)
                nums2 = nums2[1:]
                pos += 1
            if pos >= con / 2:
                if con % 2 == 0:
                    return (coffin[int(con / 2 -1)] + coffin[int(con / 2)]) / 2
                else:
                    return coffin[int(con/2)]

    for e in nums2:
        coffin.append(e)
        pos += 1
        if pos >= con / 2:
                if con % 2 == 0:
                    return (coffin[int(con / 2 -1)] + coffin[int(con / 2)]) / 2
                else:
                    return coffin[int(con/2)]
```

Comment: This outputs 2.5 in leetcode for me.

Comment: I used if statement to find what "con" the leetcode is evaluating, and it seems to be 3 for all two given inputs.

Comment: well... now I am not sure what's going on...

Comment: Ah, you are running leetcode in python2. Yes I can see case 2 gives an incorrect answer of 2.0

Comment: Could you explain why case 2 gives 2.0?

Comment: check my answer and apply the recommended change. btw you should better program in python3

Comment: Ok I'll implement yours and see whats going on with leetcode. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running python2

Change your divisions by 2  from `/2` to float divisions `/2.0`

You have two places where you are taking an average of two numbers, so divide by the floating number 2.0 instead of dividing by the integer number 2

So change

```
return (coffin[int(con / 2 -1)] + coffin[int(con / 2)]) / 2
```

for

```
return (coffin[int(con / 2 -1)] + coffin[int(con / 2)]) / 2.0
```

Comment: It works in python 2 now! thanks. well I wish I could vote but this is my first post...

Answer (score 0):

I am on the same problem and encountering the same issue. For [1,2] [3,4] I am getting 2.5 on visual code as output and 2.0 on leetcode. Here is my code:
class Solution(object):
def findMedianSortedArrays(self, nums1, nums2):
"""
:type nums1: List[int]
:type nums2: List[int]
:rtype: float
"""
# Code is correct. Gives wrong output here for [1,2], [3,4].
total_list = sorted(nums1 + nums2)
n = len(total_list)
if n % 2 == 0:
return (total_list[n//2 - 1] + total_list[n//2]) / 2
else:
return total_list[n//2]

Comment: Please do not post your own issue as an answer to another question. Feel free to create your own question.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35413295)